# Share 2 folders by same name and accessing those by IP Address

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

I am using **Window Server 2012 R2**, 
Configured multiple IPs (192.168.10.137 and 10.0.2.25) 
I have 2 folders in server 
D:\Client1\ProductData 
D:\Client2\ProductData

> Is it possible to share and access the **ProductData** folder by **ip address**? 
>   **Ex:** 
>  
>   *\\192.168.10.137\ProductData* should point to *D:\Client1\ProductData* 
>  
>   *\\10.0.2.25\ProductData* should point to *D:\Client2\ProductData*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, share name can't be identical and must be unique on the server.

Why? its because share name are stored there; SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares

Each with their name in a REG_MULTI_SZ value, consisting of its name.

So even if lanman listen to two IP, the same share list apply.

See [there](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/125996/saving-and-restoring-existing-windows-shares) for more information